# How to add multiple data to arraylist from listview button click?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview

I have a button and a Listview. Now on clicking the button, items will be added to listview. Now the listview item contains separate buttons, and on clicking that button a popup dialog will appear. I need to add the data from that popup to arraylist against each item in the listview.

Please check the image here [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyfBi.png)

On clicking the **Add Product** Button in the image above, items will be added to listview. 
Now on clicking the **Line User Defined** Button in listview, a popup dialog will appear like this ==> [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j46M.png)

I need to add the data of the popup in an arraylist on its **ok button**, which will be based on the items of the listview. For example, suppose  product1 is added to listview, so now on clicking that product's popup button and adding all the data in the popup dialog, the entire arraylist will be created based on product1.

Now suppose product2 is added to listview, then again the same thing will repeat i.e popup dialog will appear and data will be added to that same arraylist as before.
So multiple product details will be added to the arraylist.

I need the added arraylist format as below:

```
 "productUDF": [
    {
      "productCode": "128739         ",
      "Code": "F1",
      "Value": "This 'Apple' is ripe...."
    },
    {
      "productCode": "128739         ",
      "Code": "F2",
      "Value": "2018-12-12"
    }
  ]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the getView() method in your adapter you need to add your onClickListener to your butter, in that onClickListener you can call getItem(position) to select the item from the list you want to update and then call notifyDataSetChanged() after you’ve saved the changes to your item, causing the cell to update and then information to be updated also :)